# VS2013 View Layout Multiple Documents

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Back in Visual studio 2008 I was able to go to Tools > Options and change it from Tabbed Documents to Window Documents.

How do I do this in visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows.

If it isn't there perhaps it is [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EBF6137E-AA2D-4DC9-860A-F04168F11CD7)?

Comment: You know what, I'll take it.  Theres an option here to at least make FLOAT's stay on top of the window when its moved.  This gets me closer to the concept they use to offer. Thanks for the direction!